# Combining JavaScript and Less

Tags: jquery, less

I am trying to retrieve the height of a div using JQuery whilst styling it with less. Unfortunately, even after putting the JavaScript at the bottom of the page and less at the head, less seems to compile after my JavaScript.

When I retrieve width and height of a div using JQuery, I get 0. How can I fix this?

Also, I know my code works because when I load the JavaScript console after page has loaded, it works fine.

So far I have tried the `$(window).bind("load",function(){})`,`less.refresh()` and `$(document).ready()`

I did a test alert function. The alert happens before the entire page loads, which take a few more seconds

Everything happens before my elements become visible on the page

Answer (score 0):

Try the code in the following manner

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
   height=$(.yourdiv).height();
});
```

If that doesn't work then the following:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    height=$(.yourdiv).height();
});
```

Comment: This does not work. `Neither does $(window).bind("load", function(){//mycode})`; I did a test alert function. The alert happens before the entire page loads, which take a few more seconds. I even tried using `less.refresh()`

Comment: If you will please read my comment again. I did the same as you, just with slightly different syntax. I even tried the normal DOM way with `window.onload = function()`